# debugThe NTVDl CpU has encountered an illegal instruction.CS:0000 IP:0075 Opf0 00 f0 37 05 Choose 'Close' to terminate theapplication

Tags: compilation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGpOI.png)
An error was reported when continuing push.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pm73.png)

it's instruction.

```
mov ax,1000
mov ds,ax
mov bx,2000
mov ss,bx
mov sp,10
push [0]
push [2]
push [4]
push [6]
push [8]
push [A]
push [C]
push [E]
```

I don't know how to solve